# Instructions or details for the buildings in Set 190

Tags: sets, instructions

A wave of nostalgia has struck me this holiday weekend, and I have been doing some research on the kits in the big plastic tub in my closet.  Among many others, I discovered that among my collection is Set #190, Building Set with People - Farm.  I would guess this set was given to me when I was between ages four and seven, and I am now 40+.  I remembered the tractor and plow, and some sort of house with a fence around it, and the parts I have confirm the match.

However, my instruction booklet is long lost for this set, and the scans I have found on [ToysPeriod](https://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/building-set-with-people/farm/lego-190-lego-building-set-with-people-farm/) and [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/scans/190-1/) seem to have only instructions for the vehicles and animals, but not for the greenhouse, house, and barn shown in the photos.  In fact, based on the creases and location of page breaks, these two sites appear to have the same scan.  I've found other sites with even fewer pages of these instructions.

I more or less figured out the fence and greenhouse from the photos, although I ran out of clear bricks for the greenhouse so probably I made a mistake somewhere.  I may or may not have similar luck with the rest- I plan to try later.

I believe that sometimes Lego did this intentionally- put photos on the box just to give an idea or starting point.  Does anyone know if this is what happened in this case?

Are there other places I can look for instructions, or at least detailed photos from other angles to help me build this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instructions for that model are not included in the set.<sup>1</sup>

Youtube user [BrickTsar LEGO® Collector](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnScfo4T8bUEwSWbd7zd9XQ) rebuilt the model using the box as reference. The image below shows a screenshot from the video linked at the end of this post, it might be clearer to you how it was built.

[image]

The model he made isn't an exact like for like copy of the model shown on the set, but is very close. It is possible you won't use all the pieces provided in  the set but it's worth checking that you have all the parts needed before you start using the [inventory provided on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=9051-1).

<sup>1</sup> [Youtube. LEGO 190 Building Set With People Farm Set from 1975 VINTAGE. Time: 1:58.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtIFfglWLAA&feature=youtu.be&t=118)

Comment: To be clear, this video does not show the buildings in-progress nor does it show any better angles or close-ups of the buildings.  It was enough for me to have verification that instructions were not included.  I took my own stab at them, and I think I got it- at least as well as the video.

Answer (score 2):

Five years after first posting this question, I discovered stud.io.  Using my notes and photos from then, I re-built these three items again, this time in the virtual space, and posted them on bricklink:

- [The farm house](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=193301)
- [The barn](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=193299)
- [The green house](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=193294)

As before, these are just my best guesses as to how things might have been, in a set I got as a gift some time in the mid to late 1970s.  I also don't want to take anything away from Ambo100's great answer at the time.  I'm just adding this for completeness, now that I have the designs available.